# Activate the event handler of an HTML element created with MooTool's extended element

Tags: javascript

In browsing a JavaScript file, I see the following line:

```
this.close = new Element('a', {id:'close-btn', href: 'javascript:void(0);', 'class': this.typeprefix + '-deletebutton', events: {click: this.remove.bind(this)}}).inject(this.bit);
```

I'm guessing that new Element() is a MooTools extended element.   I can't seem to programmatically fire the MooTool's click event.

I tried

```
document.getElementById('close-btn').onclick.apply(document.getElementById('close-btn'));
```

but nothing happened.  Each of the following lines below gave me an undefined:

```
alert(document.getElementById('close-btn').click);
alert(document.getElementById('close-btn').onclick);
alert(document.getElementById('close-btn').events);
alert(document.getElementById('close-btn').['events']);
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to programmatically fire the anchor's click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evObj.initMouseEvent(
    'click', true, true, window,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, true, false,
    0, null
);
document.getElementById('close-btn').dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent

For IE you may try
document.getElementById('close-btn').click();
or
document.getElementById('close-btn').fireEvent("onclick");